# Options for speeding up slow SQL queries

Tags: mysql, performance

We're having issues with a few queries - relatively simple queries - that take too long processing. Everything from 3 000ms to 30 000ms. We are using PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5.28-29.1.

We have a few options, but I am posting here to see if anyone has any experience on each of them:

1. Currently we are accessing views to get our data, this was done to move the processing load from the PHP to the MySQL. Would accessing the tables directly improve the query processing speed? I'm thinking not, cause it would lead to a lot more queries, due to the fact that the views are just collations of data.
2. If we were to install a cache DB, such as SQLite3, to cache it locally, then sync it to a RDBMS, how would we do that? And would the speed improve?
3. Thinking about a NodeJS version as well, using Node WebKit. As far as I can understand there is npm packages out there that can act as cache or a db connection, which would rule out the need for PHP. But how about the speed?
4. Another option is to set up a dedicated server for this environment (we're using a virtual server environment for the moment). Which would most likely speed some parts of it up. But if the MySQL will still be slow on that server - it's kind of wasted.

These are the alternatives I can think of at the moment. Any suggestions are appreciated.

(I can post the slow SQL queries if need be, but would like to see if anyone has anything to say about our options first)

Comment: All the specified options are not good. Post your queries, output of `EXPLAIN`, your server's specs and my.cnf if you want a proper analysis. All caching done "in front" of MySQL is bad. Reason it's bad is because MySQL is able to do caching just fine, and better than other RDBMS or whatever. All you have to do is configure MySQL so it's as fast as you need it to be.

Comment: Generally Database optimization and query optimization are going to net you WAY more speed than any of the mentioned solutions.  Next, I'd fork out some cash for SSDs.  Way more effective and Way cheaper than paying development on changes that will probably only make a minor difference.

Comment: @N.B. We have outsourced our servers to another company, so we don't have total control over our servers. I will post those outputs as soon as I get them back from our provider. Also the MySQL control is out of my hands, which is why a dedicated server might be a solution to this.

Comment: What @trex005 mentioned is true as well. Also, if the servers are outsourced, I take it that the company in question is able to optimize configuration as well? Basically, you want to let MySQL as much hardware as possible. Default configuration makes it work on old, slow devices and people usually don't change that.

Comment: Often the solution to a performance problem is as simple as adding the optimal "composite" index.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on how to design such.

Comment: @N.B. This is the reply we got from our provider: "I appreciate the "all caching in front of MySQL is bad" viewpoint, but, on a shared system your'e not able to effectively leverage all of the various MySQL caches - because on a shared system the dataset is so large, and the queries so varied, the effect of the cache is almost nulled. On a dedicated or virtual dedicated server where you're the only user on there, MySQL caching is superb and the query caching can make a massive difference to performance."

Comment: @rnngau it seems (to me at least) that you're trying to use software to solve a hardware problem. It just won't work, no matter what you install - you have to spend storage space (RAM). If I were you, I'd be looking for a dedicated host. If that's not an option and you must stay with shared host - I'm afraid no software you stick there will make anything work significantly faster.